# Latest Rasa core model does not detect any entities

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

I followed the Rasa masterclass and have the following setup:

data/nlu.md:

```
## intent:search_provider
- I want to go to a  [hospital] (facilitytype)
- I am sick need to go to a [hospital] (facilitytype)
- Can you tell me how to get to a [hospital] (facilitytype)
```

rasa train:

```
2020-01-17 19:06:36 INFO     rasa.model  - Data (nlu-config) for NLU model changed.
Core stories/configuration did not change. No need to retrain Core model.
Training NLU model...
2020-01-17 19:06:36 INFO     rasa.nlu.training_data.loading  - Training data format of /var/folders/2p/c7zvhbtj4dz0p053y49fmr_h0000gp/T/tmphtg4ok5r/68c2a3993fe141b199b22b8cac047519_nlu.md is md
2020-01-17 19:06:36 INFO     rasa.nlu.training_data.training_data  - Training data stats: 
    - intent examples: 50 (8 distinct intents)
    - Found intents: 'goodbye', 'affirm', 'inform', 'search_provider', 'mood_unhappy', 'greet', 'mood_great', 'deny'
    **- entity examples: 0 (0 distinct entities)
    - found entities:**
```

When I run the nlp model, it detects the right intent, but cannot extract any entities, not sure what I am missing :

Next message:

```
I want to go to a hospital
{
  "intent": {
    "name": "search_provider",
    "confidence": 0.9632793664932251
  },
  "entities": [],
```

My pipeline has the following line in the config.yml:

```
pipeline: supervised_embeddings
```

Answer (score 1):

@user12735193 Can you specify the exact Rasa version you are using?
Also, please don't add a space between the `[entity value]` and `(entity type)`. It should be like this - `[entity value](entity type)` and not `[entity value] (entity type)`. I think that should fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @dragster, there shouldn't be a space between entity value and type:

```
## intent:inform
- [NEW YORK](city)
- I am going home to [Detroit](city)
```